# iterate a list and show bootstrap modal for each element one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get user input for some list of questions through a popup. I tried to achieve this using bootstrap modal by iterating each questions from the list but I'm not getting the expected result. please see my code below,

Is any other best suitable looping approach will help to solve my problem?

```js
var askUser = ["how are you?", "what is your age?", "where are you from?"];
index = 0;

iterate(askUser, index);

function iterate(askUser, index){
  if(index < askUser.length){
    showModal(askUser[index], index);
    
  }
}

function showModal(value, index) {
  $('.ask-user').html(value);
  $('#userData').modal('show');
}

$('#modal-submit').click(function() {
  console.log($('#input').value);
  $('#userData').modal('hide');
  iterate(askUser, index++);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="userData" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p class="ask-user">Question??</p>
                            <input type="text" id="input" class="form-control">
                            <button type="submit" id="modal-submit"class="btn btn-default pull-right">Submit</button>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: How do you expect it to be more easy?

Comment: if the word simple bothers you. sorry for that. :D  just updated the question.

Comment: You are expecting us to write a lot of code for you when you say you want to loop over a bootstrap modal, specially as you have not even attempted to use one bootstrap model for yourself!

Comment: i had tried myself but I'm facing trouble in this particular looping part. I thought the problem statement would be fine to help me. Do you guys need entire full code to help me out?

Comment: Hey @veera, we don't need ALL the code, just the relevant parts (So if this question is tagged under bootstrap, you should explain and include the bootstrap part too). Read about creating a [mcve] for more details. Thanks

Comment: @AlonEitan  Thanks. I gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working solution with bootstrap , As you see i made recursive call to the function that shows and hides the model after 2 sec

```js
var askUser = ["how are you?", "what is your age?", "where are you from?"];
var $modal = $('#myModal');
var i = 0;

showModal(askUser)

function showModal(arr) {
  $modal.modal('hide');


  setTimeout(function() {
    if (i < arr.length) {
      $('.modal-body').html(arr[i]);
      $modal.modal('show');
      i++;
    }
  }, 400)
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="next" class="btn btn-default" onclick="showModal(askUser)">next</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you're just expecting that the user will answer each question within 2 seconds... Very interesting (and terrible) UX

Comment: i tired this approach but I need the modal to be wait until user clicks 'ok' or press enter

Comment: I am going to edit it , @AlonEitan you are absolutly right i just missed up the user part

Comment: Ping me when you're done, so I could check and upvote if I find it helpful :)

Comment: @AlonEitan check it please :)

Comment: you still set the wait time. :(

Comment: no it's just for the display , i cannot hide and show at the same time , you can try to reduced it

Comment: i make an other edit check it

Comment: can you pls explain why we can't show and hide at the same time?